# add scrollable Divs inside flexbox Divs

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would like to add scrollable inside my main page layout which has left and right panel.

Inside right panel, I would like to have scrollable divs but whole Page should not have Scrollbar.

I have done the following,

```css
body{    
    height:100vh;
}

.body-container{
   backgound: yellow;
   display:flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.left-panel{
   background:red;
   flex:1;
   margin-right:1px;
}

.right-panel{
   background:green;
   display:flex;
   flex-flow:column;
   flex:3 0 auto;  
}

.content-container{
   display:flex;
   flex-direction:column;
   flex:1;
}
.fixed-header{
   background:lightGreen;
}
.scrollable-content{
   flex:1;
   overflow-y:auto;
   background:lightBlue;
}
```

```html
<div class="body-container">
    <div class="left-panel">
        <p> Left Panel </p>
    </div>
    <div class="right-panel">
        <p> Right Panel </p>
        <div class="content-container">
            <div class="fixed-header">
                <p> Fixed header </p>
                <p> Fixed header </p>
                <p> Fixed header </p>
                <p> Fixed header </p>
                <p> Fixed header </p>
                <p> Fixed header </p>
            </div>
            <div class="scrollable-content">
                <p> Scrollable </p>
                <p> Scrollable </p>
                <p> Scrollable </p>
                <p> Scrollable </p>
                <p> Scrollable </p>
                <p> Scrollable </p>
                <p> Scrollable </p>
                <p> Scrollable </p>
                <p> Scrollable </p>
                <p> Scrollable </p>
                <p> Scrollable </p>
                <p> Scrollable </p>
                <p> Scrollable </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can any one help me with this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found way, where we do not need to setup a height on Child divs to  make it scrollable.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.body-container {
  flex: 1: background: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
}
.left-panel {
  background: red;
  flex: 1
}
.right-panel {
  background: green;
  flex: 3;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.content-container {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.fixed-header {} .scrollable-content {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="body-container">
  <div class="left-panel">
    <p>My Left Panel</p>
  </div>
  <div class="right-panel">
    <p>Test My Right Panel</p>
    <div class="content-container">
      <div class="fixed-header">
        <p>Fixed header</p>
        <p>Fixed header</p>
        <p>Fixed header</p>
      </div>

      <div class="scrollable-content">
        <p>Scrollable</p>
        <p>Scrollable</p>
        <p>Scrollable</p>
        <p>Scrollable</p>
        <p>Scrollable</p>
        <p>Scrollable</p>
        <p>Scrollable</p>
        <p>Scrollable</p>
        <p>Scrollable</p>
        <p>Scrollable</p>
        <p>Scrollable</p>
        <p>Scrollable</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does not work in Firefox 61.0.1 64-bit on Windows 8.1 Pro.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, added max height and overflow-y to scroll.

```css
body{    
    height:100vh;
    }

.body-container{
  backgound: yellow;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.left-panel{
  background:red;
  flex:1;
  margin-right:1px;
}

.right-panel{
  background:green;
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:column;
  flex:3 0 auto;  
}

.content-container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  flex:1;
}
.fixed-header{
   background:lightGreen;
}
.scrollable-content{
  flex:1;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  max-height:200px;
  background:lightBlue;
}
```

```html
<div class="body-container">
<div class="left-panel">
<p>
Left Panel
</p>
</div>
<div class="right-panel">
<p>
Right Panel
</p>
<div class="content-container">
<div class="fixed-header">
<p>
Fixed header
</p>
<p>
Fixed header
</p>
<p>
Fixed header
</p>
<p>
Fixed header
</p>
<p>
Fixed header
</p>
<p>
Fixed header
</p>
</div>

<div class="scrollable-content">
<p>
Scrollable
</p>
<p>
Scrollable
</p>
<p>
Scrollable
</p>
<p>
Scrollable
</p>
<p>
Scrollable
</p>
<p>
Scrollable
</p>
<p>
Scrollable
</p>
<p>
Scrollable
</p>
<p>
Scrollable
</p>
<p>
Scrollable
</p>
<p>
Scrollable
</p>
<p>
Scrollable
</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the following what you are looking for?: http://codepen.io/Skibbereen-Coderdojo/pen/BpbROm

I just added a height to your `.scrollable-content` rule

```
.scrollable-content{
  flex:1;
  overflow-y:auto;
  background:lightBlue;
  height: 100vh; /*Constrain the height */
}
```

Adding a fixed height will constrain your `.scrollable-content` and then your `overflow-y:auto;` will kick in and take care of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Mention height for the div to be scrolled. and enable scroll-y:auto.

Added a fiddle for you:

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/Safoora/cpcygkno/6/`

Hope it will help.
```